# Хостинг для telegram бота на вебхуке

Tags: telegram, vps, бот

Собственно, назрел такой вопрос: т.к. телега работает с вебхуками только на четырех портах (80, 443, 88, 8443), можно ли хостить бота на vps с проброской портов? Или важен именно конечный порт на моем апаче? Не силен в сетевой маршрутизации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Важен порт на который телеграм будет присылать сообщения, т.е. внешний порт, что там с ним внутри дальше уже не важно. Если будет неправильный порт, то телеграм сразу выдаст понятную ошибку

Comment: Ну, я, в принципе, так и думал. Значит нельзя